# Do public keys make Kerberos more secure (RFC4556)?

Tags: linux, macos, kerberos

We're using [IPA](http://freeipa.org/page/Main_Page) to centralize our authentication and I found an option to add a public key for each user. After doing a little research I found this to be an extension to Kerberos 5, RFC4556.

From my understanding of how Kerberos works, it doesn't actually send the password. So I'm wondering: How does public keys add to the security of Kerberos? Is it something I should be using?

As a side note: We have some Mac users in our office, and unfortunately pkinit is missing. I haven't been able to find much about why this is, other than [this post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/fed-talk/2011/Jan/msg00012.html) on the Apple mailing list saying *"we highly recommend against using this for any purpose"*. Is this because of the security of RFC4556, or the security of how the platform used that protocol?

Comment: As far as I remember, there was a semi-practical attack on Kerberos crypto, when symmetric encryption is used.

Answer (score 2):

From [RFC4556](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4556) :

> In the AS exchange, the KDC reply contains the ticket session key,
> among other items, that is encrypted using a key (the AS reply key)
> shared between the client and the KDC.  The AS reply key is typically
> derived from the client's password for human users.  Therefore, for
> human users, the attack resistance strength of the Kerberos protocol
> is no stronger than the strength of their passwords.

Therefore PKI extension is supposed to improve security of this initial Authentication Service exchange.